# Limiting a user's action to happen only once

Tags: php

I want to know if it is possible with PHP to make action only happen once.

I have a script where users click an image and gain points for clicking it, but I would like to make it so that if they click again it won't add points anymore for a certain amount of time, or an advertisement would disappear from the site for that particular user.

Is this possible?

Comment: use coockies..........

Comment: Definitly do not use cookies. Store it server side so the user can't manipulate the data. if this is to be stored persistant then I wouldn't store it in the session either, I'd store it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in the database.
When they click on the image, run a query that changes the `is_clicked` column (for instance) to clicked or 1 or whatever you like.

Retrieve the image in such a way that, if the is_clicked column is changed to clicked for a particular user, then don't allow any clicks.

For example :

```
if($row['is_clicked'] != 'clicked']){
     echo '<img>....</img>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but with PHP, it can get pretty messy. I would suggest you use JS (Javascript). Create a simple function in JS and then use the onclick attribute in the the button element to execute. Like this:-

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('id of the button').onclick='myFunc';
   function myfunc(){
         document.getElementById('id of the button').style.display="block";
   }
</script>
```

Front end, html:

```
<button id="id of the button">Click here!</button>
```

Now if you want to make sure a person who clicks button from a computer shouldn't be able to click it again, then you should set up a cookie using php which will retrieve data about its computer and prevent the computer from using this button